# How to convert existing ios project into sub project?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an iOS project with pods. How an I convert it into a sub-project for easy inclusion into another project?

Comment: What does the project currently build? Have you looked at other 3rd party libraries to see what they do?

Answer (score -1):

You can use git submodules. It is very easy to set up.
http://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules